# The problem of designing, inserting and deleting of the B+ tree values

Tags: indexing, nodes, insertion, b-plus-tree

I have the question regarding my homework:

1) First of all, assuming that 4 pointers might fit in an internal node and each leaf node can store 4 key values, the B+ tree should be constructed with the following values:

2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31.

With [the site](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BPlusTree.html), I've received the tree below. I am not sure if it is right, because the in the leaf nodes, there might have three key values:

[image]

The problem starts with an insertion and deletion. Consequently inserting 9, 10, 8, I've received the tree below:

[image]

But when I delete 23, I describes as below. The problem is, 19 couldn't be alone, since the leaf must be half-full:

[image]

The deleting 19 after that gives the same problem:

[image]

The questions are:

1) is the initial tree is correct?

2) Are my assumptions about deletions are correct?

3) And how must be trees lookalike after the deletion?

With regards.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting 23, you are correct that that leaf node cannot exist if it has less than n/2 keys. There are basically 3 cases for a deletion in B+ Tree:

**Case 1: Node still has more than n/2 keys; no changes needed.**

If node has less than n/2 keys,

**Case 2: Borrow a key from a neighbour leaf node. Update parent nodes.**

If none of my neighbours have enough to spare me a key,

**Case 3: Merge with a neighbour leaf node. Update parent nodes.**

In the case of deleting key 23, the node containing key 19 will look to merge with either of its neighbours. After merging, remember to update your parent nodes!